# Can not get JSON object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Hey, under this url 1234/?fmt=json I create a json object like that

```
SurveyJson = {question:$("#question").val(),choice:Choice,count:Count};
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(SurveyJson);
```

and I am trying to retrieve the json object through a AJAX call

```
var url = "1234?fmt=json";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "get",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { 
        $("#display").html(data);
    }
});
```

How come I cant display the data? I have tried that if I cross out the dataType parameter and keep others the same, I can get the json string somehow, which I dont know why. And I couldnt help but noticed that some people who have the similar problem put "post" as type instead of "get", why is that if that is correct? thank you

Comment: Why do you need to get the data as json if you only want to put in a div? You should get the data in text format if you want to display it. (A json object is not a json string)

Comment: JSON.stringify(SurveyJson) that is the only thing I know cuz I am new to json, if this is not a json object? How do I create one? Thank you

Comment: @Clinteney Oscar meant you are outputting it incorrectly.  Output it like `$("#display").html(data.question);`.  The `.question` means you want to get the value for that key.

Comment: if you navigate to "1234?fmt=json" in a web browser what content is displayed when you view source? Does it match the first two lines of code in your question? If so, those two lines aren't valid syntax for jquery to parse into a json object

Comment: Man, I am totally lost, what do you mean by that? Thank you

Comment: Basically i want you to take the url you are trying to make the AJAX call to, and open a web browser and paste that into the address bar.  I am trying to find out what data exactly is being returned from that url. If you can, post the url here and I'll look myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your "callback url" 1234/?fmt=json only returns json

for example try hard coding values and see if it works, change the code at that url to output this as your http response and remove the other stuff. just respond with exactly whats shown on this line and nothing else.

```
{question:"my question",choice:"a choice",count:3}
```

Change your calling code to:

```
var url = "1234?fmt=json";
 $.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function (data) { 
        alert(data);
        alert(data.question);
    }
});
```

If you see two alert boxes; the first one with a contents of "[Object object]" (this varies slightly depending on browser) and a second alert with "my question" then you are off to a good start.  Post back and let me know and we'll take it from there.

Also, setting the "type" attribute to "get" or "post" makes no difference in regards to parsing the response text of your http request to 1234/?fmt=json, into a valid json object in the browser.  Get and Post have important differences but nothing relevant to parsing the response text of your http request.

Comment: keep in mind the intent of this post is just to get you to the point where you are returning valid json from the server. after that we can get you the rest of the way.

Comment: well, Thank you for helping me that much, I just began my journey in json. what I did under 1234?fmt=json is that I did this SurveyJson = {question:$("#question").val(),choice:Choice,count:Count};
 var jsonString = JSON.stringify(SurveyJson); hopefully I convert the javascprit object into json object, but somebody said that that is json string instead of a json object and that is the only thing I learnd from json.org, to use stringify

Comment: therefore, I alerted the data from the AJAX, and it gave me a whole page in html instead of a json object like you said... I dont know how to create a json object.. Thank you

Comment: Think of JSON as javascript code.  JSON stand for javascript object notation.  If you do this in javascript  alert({});   You will notice an alert box with [Object object]   If you wrote in javascript var x = "{}"; you have made a string, whose contents look like json. if you write var x = {}; in javascript you have created an object using JSON(javascript object notation) if you alert(x); you get [Object object]  {} is JSON notation for an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the dataType then by default it will return as html (which will be one long string).  I recommend outputting the data as a string (by making the dataType 'html' or removing it), and using this [JSON validator](http://www.jsonlint.com/) to make sure the problem isn't there.

GET and GET define the method of the request.  GET will take advantage of the query string (url).  You want to use GET, based on your example url.  Change your ajax call to this
`$.ajax({
    url: '1234',
    type: "get",
    data: { 'fmt': 'json' },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { 
        $("#display").html(data);
    }
});`